# can someone please suggest best way of doing log analysis using spark streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, log-analysis

I am completely new to Big Data, from last few weeks i am try to build log analysis application.

I read many articles and i found Kafka + spark streaming is the most reliable configuration.

Now, I am able to process data sent from my simple kafka java producer to spark Streaming.

Can someone please suggest few things like 
1) how can i read server logs real time and pass it to kafka broker.
2) any frameworks available to push data from logs to Kafka?
3) any other suggestions??

Thanks,
Chowdary

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to collect logs and send to Kafka. If you are looking to send log files as stream of events I would recommend to review Logstash/Filebeats - just setup you input as fileinput and output to Kafka.

You may also push data to Kafka using log4j KafkaAppender or pipe logs to Kafka using many CLI tools already available.

In case you need to guarantee sequence, pay attention to partition configuration and partition selection logic. For example, log4j appender will distribute messages across all partitions. Since Kafka guarantees sequence per partition only, your Spark streaming jobs may start processing events out of sequence.